# FutureBuilder keeps retuning null

Tags: flutter, api

Below is the Widget that returns data

```
class _MyProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {

  Future<user> _getUserInfo() async {
    var _userData = await UserCaller.getProfile();
    print('_userData');
    return _userData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(widget.title),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(33, 114, 243, 1),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<user>(
            future : _getUserInfo(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<user> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return  Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(top: 140, left: 140, child: _firstName(snapshot.data!.firstName)),
              Positioned(top: 180, left: 140, child: _lastName(snapshot.data!.lastName)),
              Positioned(top: 220, right: 50, child: _email(snapshot.data!.email)),
              Positioned(top: 260, left: 120, child: _phone(snapshot.data!.phoneNumber)),
              Positioned(top: 380, left: 40, child: _editProfile()),
              Positioned(top: 380, left: 140, child: _pastRides()),
              Positioned(top: 380, left: 250, child: _dashBoard()),
            ],
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }

        // By default, show a loading spinner.
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Below is the model that is marshalled in the response.

```
class user {
  String uid;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;
  String password;
  int phoneNumber;

  user(
      {required this.uid,
      required this.firstName,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.email,
      required this.password,
      required this.phoneNumber});

factory user.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
  return user(
    uid : json['uid'],
    firstName: json['FirstName'],
    lastName:  json['LastName'],
    email : json['Email'],
    password: json['password'],
    phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber'],
  );
}
}
```

API caller class

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
class UserCaller{
  static Future<user> getProfile() async {
    String profile = auth.currentUser!.email.toString();
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8080/user/'+profile));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return user.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)['data']);
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }

  UserCaller();
}
```

the snapshot.hasData always return false because the data is null despite using async and await, from what I understand that FutureBuilder wait for the widget to be loaded and return its data. Also, I tried using initState and It also did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you see on the logs if you add `print(snapshot);` before `if (snapshot.hasData) { ...`?

Comment: What are you getting in logs on printing  `_userData`  in  `_getUserInfo()`?

Comment: @pskink when I print(snapshot) I get the following error ```I/flutter (21909): AsyncSnapshot<user>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', #0      UserCaller.getProfile (package:fe_tare2k/net/API_callers/user_API_caller.dart:13:53)
``` and snapshot.data returns null.

Comment: @AshutoshAswal It prints nothing.

Comment: The response body outputs the json data correctly,  line 13 contains the following line ```return user.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)['data']);```

Comment: It is weird because ```response.body```  outputs : {"firstname":"user","user2":"mashaly","email":"user.okay@gmail.com","phone":1214041220}, while jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] prints nothing.

Comment: Still it outputs nothing.

Comment: It prints {"firstname":"user","user2":"mashaly","email":"user.okay@gmail.com","phone":1214041220}, I suspect now the error from user.fromJson method.

Comment: The output changed, it outputs ```I/flutter (21909): AsyncSnapshot<user>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String', #0      new user.fromJson (package:fe_tare2k/Model/User.dart:18:20)
```

Comment: It is a class defined in the problem statement above.

Comment: yes, the error comes from ['json'] keyword.

Comment: It worked, Thank you for your time and effort, much appreciated :D @pskink, If you do not mind to delete most of these comments and answer it so it become easier if someone had the same problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you again, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the key in the json map in `factory user.fromJson` method should be similar to the compatible class variable names in the API. For example, if you are developing an API in spring java and want to connect it with flutter, the class `entity` attributes which represents the table in your database should have column names similar to the key names in json, if you have column firstname, the in factory method should be json['firstname'] not json['firstName'].